# Groß-/Kleinschreibung nach "etwas"

Tags: capitalization

Wie verhält sich das mit der Groß-/Kleinschreibung nach dem Wörtchen "etwas"?

Ich habe, glaube ich, mal im Duden nachgesehen, da wurde empfohlen, "anderes" nach "etwas" klein zu schreiben.

> … und dann ist etwas anderes geschehen. (anstatt "… und dann ist etwas Anderes geschehen.")
>
> Ich habe etwas anderes gekauft. (anstatt "Ich habe etwas Anderes gekauft.")

1. Stimmt das überhaupt?
2. Ist das generell nach "etwas" so?

Man denke nur an:

> Dieses Rezept ist etwas einfaches. Die Blume dort ist etwas schönes. Das ist etwas ganz normales.

Oder doch:

> Dieses Rezept ist etwas Einfaches. Die Blume dort ist etwas Schönes. Das ist etwas ganz Normales.

3. Falls beide Schreibweisen möglich sind, gibt es eine Empfehlung?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wahrscheinlich denkst du an den Duden-Eintrag [D77](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/Gro%C3%9F-%20und%20Kleinschreibung#D77)

> 1. Die Wörter viel, wenig, [der] eine, [der] andere können großgeschrieben werden, wenn ihr substantivischer Charakter hervorgehoben werden soll <§ 58 E4>.
> 2. In der Regel werden sie jedoch mit allen ihren Deklinations- und Steigerungsformen kleingeschrieben.

Wie immer gelten auch nach dem Wort *etwas* die Regeln der [Substantivierung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substantivierung). [Im Normalfall folgt nach dem Wort *etwas* allerdings immer eine Substantivierung](https://www.korrekturen.de/forum.pl/md/read/id/6957/sbj/etwas-substantivierung/), also Großschreibung.

Duden-Eintrag [D72](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/Gro%C3%9F-%20und%20Kleinschreibung#D77)

> Häufig zeigen vorangehende Wörter wie alles, etwas, nichts, viel, wenig den substantivischen Gebrauch an.

Ausnahme sind allerdings die oben genannten Wörter. Bei ihnen ist, wie gesagt, die [Kleinschreibung empfohlen](https://www.korrekturen.de/wortliste/etwas_anderes.shtml), auch wenn beides möglich ist.

Eine [Besonderheit](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substantivierung#Substantivierung_von_Adjektiven,_Partizipien_und_Zahlw%C3%B6rtern) hat das Wörtchen *etwas* allerdings noch

> Wenn dem substantivierten Adjektiv eines der Indefinitpronomen jemand, niemand, etwas oder wer vorausgeht, kommt es standardsprachlich zu einer abweichenden Beugung. Im Nominativ und Akkusativ folgt die Endung -es (jemand Unbekanntes, niemand Bekanntes treffen, sie möchte wen Nettes kennenlernen); im Dativ folgt die Endung -em (mit jemand Unbekanntem). Regional und von der Standardsprache abweichend sind jedoch auch andere Formen üblich und zulässig.

Comment: Ich verstehe nicht, worin die im letzten Zitat genannte Abweichung besteht.

Comment: "Im Normalfall ... immer " ist ein Widerspruch in sich. Entweder immer oder nur im Normalfall.